backref in customized footnotes
A complementary question to Display text instead of footnote marker (customized footnotes with non-superscript footnote mark)
When I define customfootnotes as explained in the related question, I lost backreference of the footnotes (by clicking on the footer's footnotemark using footnotebackref). Is there a way to add something in the definition of customfootnotes to keep/add this functionality ?
Thanks a lot !
A MWE (from egreg answer in the related question)

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\NewDocumentCommand{\customfootnote}{o+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{#1}% Use custom text if optional argument is provided
  }%
  \footnote{#2}%
  \endgroup
}

\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}% just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

azerty\customfootnote{standard text} % Uses standard numbering

azerty\customfootnote[super]{custom text} % Uses "super" as the marker

azerty\customfootnote{standard text} % Uses standard numbering

\end{document}



your code doesn't use footnotebackref and so doesn't demonstrate your problem. This means it is not an example.

Thanks for your comment. Actually, I could add a \usepackage{footnotebackref}, but it would not be of any use - As I said, the footnotebackref solution does not work, and I am looking for another solution. I will add it as you recommend anyway

For those it may help, I simply adapted the code of footnotebackref.sty and from the post that led to the footnotebackref package.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\noindent\makebox[2.5em][r]{\mbox{\hyperref[\myFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}}\,}#1}


\NewDocumentCommand{\customfootnote}{o+m}{%
\begingroup
\IfValueT{#1}{%
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\refstepcounter{myHyperFootnoteCounter}\def\myFootnoteTag{hfn:\themyHyperFootnoteCounter}%
\label{\myFootnoteTag}\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}% Use custom text if optional argument is provided
}\footnote{#2}\,%
\endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
...

Two details :

first, the above code does work for scrbook class. I did not tested it for the usual book class.
second, the \textit{\textbf{ is just here to format the footnotemark in the footnote. I am sure there are more elegant ways..

